# Arduino-controlled slot cars - alternative to MOSFETs for speed control?

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm attempting to control the speed of two slot cars in a set using Arduino.

[image]

Each car is controlled by a controller with a variable resistor that looks like this:

[image]

They're wired in parallel to the same 17V DC power supply:

[image]

Simplified:

[image]

For Arduino control, I experimented with manipulating a single car's speed using a MOSFET. It worked really well. Using a PWM output on the Arduino, I was able to pulse the MOSFET on and off to throttle the current and change the car's speed. The behavior of the MOSFET seemed to be exactly the same as the variable resistor controller; the resistance, voltage, and current fluctuated the same way on various parts of the circuit.

Enter car B. I added a MOSFET to the setup and mimicked the MOSFET wiring for car A, grounding them both to the Arduino ground. The result looks like this:

[image]

Here's a sketch:

[image]

Close up, MOSFET A:

[image]

MOSFET B:

[image]

At first, all seemed well. I sent signals to MOSFET A and successfully changed Car A's speed. I stopped Car A and pulsed MOSFET B, and I was able to control Car B's speed just fine.

Then, I turned Car B to a constant speed, and sent a signal to MOSFET A while Car B was still running. Car A started, but Car B's speed immediately dropped as a result of running Car A.

I hooked a multimeter up across the rails of Car B and watched its voltage while it ran on its own. Then, sure enough, when Car A started running alongside it, Car B's voltage dropped dramatically.

I figured this was because of my wiring configuration, so I left the multimeter on Car B, and made one change. I replaced MOSFET A with the original slot car controller:

[image]

I started running Car B again using its MOSFET. The multimeter showed a steady voltage, so I began to squeeze Car A's controller (the variable resistor), and Car A's speed increased. This time, however, unlike using a MOSFET to control Car A, the variable resistor did not affect Car B's voltage at all. Car B remained at a steady speed the whole time.

Any idea why this happens? The MOSFET seemed to function the same as the variable resistor (empirically) with a single car, but had totally different behavior with two cars in parallel. Is it because the MOSFET is not really changing resistance to current, but just switching it on and off, so it opens up another path for current to flow fully every time it closes? Is there an Arduino-controllable alternative to a MOSFET that would fluctuate actual resistance like the variable resistor? Digital potentiometer? Servo hooked up to a potentiometer? ;) I'm really curious what the difference is and what causes the major differences in behavior.

Comment: I hate to ask, but did you double-check that you connected between the busses for power and ground on your breadboard?  I see the orange jumper, but no others.

Comment: Good catch. You did help me notice one missing jumper. I meant to connect the two grounds up top so there was a shorter path out of the MOSFET to ground. But, I'm probably being a bit unconventional in how I set it up, in that the two power busses on either side on the bottom are connected to the positive controller lines for the cars, while the two ground busses up top are connected to their respective negatives. So, it's ok for the ground lines to be connected between controllers (since they are inside the slot car set anyway), but I intentionally kept the two positives separate.

Comment: What's the resistance range on the original controllers? What happens if you hook both MOSFETs to the same PWM signal?

Comment: can you please add a sketch of how the mosfets are connected, the Gate, drain and source.  And how the gate is interfaced to the Arduino ....

Comment: @mng I measured a range of 3-45 Ohms on the original controllers.

Comment: @smashtastic A new sketch of the MOSEFETs is added above.

Comment: Slot cars use a fair amount of current, breadboards and breadboard jumpers can have significant resistance, and the MOSFETs are going to be sensitive to any voltage drop in their source wire.  I would suggest that rather than having the supply wire enter the top rail and then having current for both MOSFETs go through a single red jumper wire, you should connect the ground to three breadboard-compatible wires using a solid connection (not the breadboard itself) and then have one of those wires connect to each MOSFET source and have the third connect to the Arduino.

Comment: Thus, the current feeding each car will only have to go through one short length of breadboard wire (between the main ground wire and the breadboard), and two breadboard holes, and those connections won't be shared between the two cars.  As it is, the current for both cars has to go through a shared red jumper wire and three shared breadboard holes.  If the connecting ground wires off-board would be difficult, you could try as a start replacing the orange jumper with another red jumper from the top rail to the left half of the bottom ground rail.

Comment: the power and ground jumpers were sloppy and unfiltered without care to using ferrite,low ESR caps and twisted pair wiring to load. Attention to these details will improve breadboard performance immensely!! Students take note! ALso use braided wire distributed along the tracks to reduce ESR of source pwr/gnd.

Comment: @supercat I tried your suggestions, and while they seem like a definite improvement, just for the sake of having better MOSFET connections, it didn't seem to mitigate the voltage drop problem any.

Comment: Did you finally solve the problem? Would you mind sharing? Thks.

Comment: @pakman, I just added my final solution and selected it as best answer. I used this part from SparkFun, which works like a charm: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding that the [L298](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000240.pdf) driver provided all the circuitry internally to control two motors separately and keep them isolated. It worked really well using the part directly, but it needs some extra stuff to control heat. This got complicated pretty quickly, just like trying to isolate the MOSFETs did.

Finally, I settled on buying this motor driver from SparkFun, which uses the L298 at its core:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9670

It has worked incredibly well for months, and it was a good investment to not have to design the circuit around the L298 myself. Plus, it adds a few extra really nice-to-have features and packages it all together in a nice board with screw terminals for your power supply and motors.

Answer (score 1):

YOu are entering a world where Electro Magnetic Compatibility is at risk. Pay attention to the stray current spikes that radiate noise (Egress) and their influence on other circuits of high impedance (Ingress). YOu probably also have ripple or the conducted egress and ingress as well.

For radiated noise a handy tool is a small AM radio (not FM) nearby, to locate such noise issues if you dont have a scope.

Noise suppression management may include some common mode chokes to the track or pot lines. Perhaps some supply rail filtering may need to be added around the track.

I would use ferrite beads for each driver with caps after the bead and then use twisted pairs to send the current after going thru a ferrite torroid or similar [**common mode choke**](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/FB20011-3B-RC/M8695-ND/775234), like those used in Video cables. 
Its good to have a [**kit of parts for such issues.**](http://www.digikey.ca/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?vendor=0&keywords=ferrite)

Add decoupling caps to the breadboard for both sides.

Comment: Not sure this addresses the problem. Whilst PWM on small brushed DC motors is bound to generate a lot of noise, I am not sure it can be blame for the observations.

Comment: Ingress from adjacent cars will propagate to loading effects on drivers and source ripple on DC power on the tracks. It will be stemming from both radiated and conducted noise from motors and depends on distributed wiring of DC along tracks. But this interaction of the race will significantly reduce the performance of each motor. Proof: If a DC motor on a track will gain speed by simply putting a low ESR(10mΩ) Cap across the motor, then **Ingress/egress is an issue**. In this case, conducted. Of course it will run hotter and burn out sooner but it will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your two PWMs are in phase: on at the same time, off at the same time. This is likely to cause the voltage to drop at the output of the power supply. Try a large electrolytic capacitor of suitable voltage rating across the power supply, and making sure that your PWMs are out of phase.

You should also have a diode connected in parallel with your driver MOSFETs, in the normally non-conducting direction. This shouldn't make much functional difference other than avoiding damage to the MOSFETs from back EMF.

Comment: I'm going to look into the phase issue. That's along the original lines of what I was thinking could be the problem, but didn't know where to start looking. I'll post back what I find out..

Comment: As I think about this more, wouldn't I still always have them on at the same time on occasion no matter how I shift the phase? Even if the cycles started at different points on the timer, if both cars ran at full speed, they would overlap each other, and still have difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You have got diodes across the motors so that is ok...

I think you problem is one of current, a breadboard and the jumper wires will limit the current flowing to the motors from the supply, you need a thicker wire for the common ground from the FETs to the supply negative.

One motor is ok, but when you start to use two, the extra current will cause problems.

Try taking 2 identical jumper wires from the motor supply ground, and have 1 to each fet source pin (leave the other wires to your ground rail on the bread board (Yes you will get a ground loop, but for testing this will prove if the breadboard / links are limiting the current))

Comment: This seems to make a lot of sense, and I'll give it a try. At the very least, it's an improvement to my current setup. The only thing that kind of throws a wrench in that thought for me is that the exact same circuit works fine if I replace one of the MOSFETs with the original variable resistor controller. Shouldn't I still face the same current issues in that case, or is there a different principle at work?

Comment: No dice. I just hooked everything up per @supercat's suggestions above, and have the same issue.